# My popup does not close when clicked anywhere in the background using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript

I know that there are many questions and answers pertaining this, but i have tried but am still unable to do so. Please help.

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(clicklistener); // once ready, run clicklistener function 
function clicklistener() {
$(".image-thumbnail").click(popup); // run popup function when ".image-thumbnail" is clicked} 

function popup() {
var srcname = $(this).attr("src"); // get source image filename
var newfile = srcname.replace("small", "large"); // replace with large img

if ($(this).parent().children("span").children("img").hasClass("image-popup")) { // traverse the elements to check if the image popup already exists
    $(this).parent().children("span").remove(); // remove if it already exists
} else {
    var printimg = "<span><img class=\"image-popup\"src=\"" + newfile + "\"></img></span>";
    $(this).after(printimg); // create img if it doesn't exist
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you have an event defined for closing it (unless you click on the popup).  SO you need to write one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".image-thumbnail").click(function(){
    // allow for body.click to first hide any current images
    setTimeout(function(){popup($(this))}, 600)); // run popup function when ".image-thumbnail" is clicked
  });

  function popup($ele) {
    var srcname = $ele.attr("src"); // get source image filename
    var newfile = srcname.replace("small", "large"); // replace with large img

    if ($ele.parent().children("span").children("img").hasClass("image-popup")) { // traverse the elements to check if the image popup already exists
      $ele.parent().children("span").remove(); // remove if it already exists
    } else {
      var printimg = "<span><img class=\"image-popup\"src=\"" + newfile + "\"></img></span>";
    $ele.after(printimg); // create img if it doesn't exist
    }
  }

  $(window).click(function(){
    $('.image-popup').remove()
  });
})
```

Comment: Also want to mention you can probably shorten setTimeout from 1000 to 500 if you need it to go faster

Comment: thanks for the response. However when i tried it out, it doesnt seem to work, and there are no error messages

Comment: OK, I change the answer.  Try is now